# Creating series of rectangular polygons along line using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I am trying to create a series of rectangular polygons following a line feature in ArcMap. I want to use these polygons as an index layer to create data driven pages.

This tool in ArcGIS Pro seems to be what I am looking for: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-rectangles-along-lines.htm

Is there a similar option in ArcMap?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool [Strip Map Index Features (Cartography)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/strip-map-index-features.htm) does exactly what I was looking for because it:

> Creates a series of rectangular polygons, or index features, that
> follow a single linear feature or a group of linear features. These
> index features can be used with Data Driven Pages to define pages in a
> strip map or a set of maps that follow a linear feature. The resulting
> index features contain attributes that can be used to rotate and
> orient the map on the page and determine which index features, or
> pages, are next to the current page (to the left and right or to the
> top and bottom).